# How to transform typescript code to javascript

Tags: typescript

These are the errors that I get

index.ts:11:4 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.

11 ): Promise => {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

index.ts:26:44 - error TS2550: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2017' or later.

26       `Request failed with status ${Object.entries(
~~~~~~~

index.ts:28:20 - error TS2550: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2017' or later.

28       )}, ${Object.entries(exactErrorMsg)}`
~~~~~~~

Found 3 errors in the same file, starting at: index.ts:11

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2017",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
interface LoginResponse {
  token: string;
  email: string;
  role: string;
}

// login function call to API
const login = async (
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<LoginResponse> => {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/auth/login";

  // API call
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    const exactErrorMsg = await res.json();
    throw new Error(
      `Request failed with status ${Object.entries(
        res.status
      )}, ${Object.entries(exactErrorMsg)}`
    );
  }

  // return response
  const data: LoginResponse = await res.json();

  // set token using document.cookie
  document.cookie = `token=${data.token}`;

  console.log(document.cookie);

  return data;
};
```

I get the above error when I run

```
tsc index.ts
```

Comment: You probably just want `target` to be `es2017` or `esnext`, but you're not actually using your tsconfig.  `tsc index.ts` doesn't consult tsconfig.  See the linked q/a for more information.

Comment: You're right. The links provide the solution. I ran 
tsc
and it works.